# Problem while installing ros navigation

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i'm having some problem trying install ros-kinetic-navigation on ubuntu 16.04, it tells me:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-kinetic-navigation : Depends: ros-kinetic-map-server but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If i try to install ros-kinetic-map-server it tells me:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-kinetic-map-server : Depends: libsdl-image1.2-dev but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: libsdl1.2-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And it goes deeper and deeper.
I've tried to reinstall ros with no results.

*EDIT*: **SOLVED**
Solved using aptitude:

```
sudo aptitude install libsdl-image1.2-dev
```

And follow its instructions

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346332/problem-while-installing-ros-navigation/) by [BlueSkeptical](https://answers.ros.org/users/51641/blueskeptical/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2020-03-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-10**:
Please post your last edit as an answer, and then accept your own answer.

Please also include a short description of *what* the solution/instructions actually was/were.

**Comment by [BlueSkeptical](https://answers.ros.org/users/51641/blueskeptical/) on 2020-03-10**:
Done, but I need 10 points to accept my own answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Solved:**
Install aptitude.
Then:

```
sudo aptitude install libsdl-image1.2-dev
```

It will find you all the needed dependencies and ask you if you want to install them.

---

Originally posted by [BlueSkeptical](https://answers.ros.org/users/51641/blueskeptical/) with karma: 18 on 2020-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0